# how to add controls for a game using batch files?

Tags: batch-file, user-controls, move

I am attempting to make a platform game using batch files. I know this seems like a waste of time and there are better tools out there but I just wanted try it out. How do you set up controls so my character moves, jump, gravity and collision? Here's a link to a vid that shows a platform game made in batch file:   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_Egqa0Gqhc

Comment: Please make your question more specific, 'how do i code a game using batch files' is far too vague. 'How do I read input from the keyboard in Windows batch files?' for example.

Comment: What do you mean by "controls"? What do you have so far? Are you **really** talking about windows `.cmd` scripts?

Comment: sorry about that all, fileoffset your correct I do want to read input from the keyboard in windows batch files. When I mean by controls I mean by the keyboard, I want to make my character move with the keyboard keys like in most platform games. up, left, right arrows.(up to jump) thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with reading [Batch Minesweeper](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=585) and [pacman](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=597) to learn a bit about batch gaming.

But to handle the arrow keys you need always an external program, as choice can't handle them.
With choice you could use "normal" letters, so you could use ASDW to move instead of the arrow keys, but choice is not available in XP.

And you should know how to start and communicate between multiple batch processes.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is try useing the bscript engine that way you will already the stuff that you need to make ur game but, consider the manual is extreme not like hugh extreme ment a bit confusing and take time to settle . Considering theyre trying to make the engine very fliud in batch script which is hugh lol